# Change WooCommerce text string "Order #" to "Internet Order #"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Seems like it should be simple, but I can't figure out how to change the strings **"Order #"** in emails or **"Order Number"** in Thank You page.

I want both to read **"Web Order #"** and **"Web Order Number**" respectively.

I have tried:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'translate_woocommerce_strings', 999, 3 );

function translate_woocommerce_strings( $translated, $untranslated, $domain ) {
   if ( ! is_admin() && 'woocommerce' === $domain ) {
      switch ( $translated) {
         case 'Order' :
            $translated = 'Web Order';
            break;
      }
   }     
   return $translated;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the thankyou page you can apply the same as the example above for the e-mails, 
on the following line you will find what you are looking for

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.8.0/templates/checkout/thankyou.php#L45

> - This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed email by copying email-order-details.php to child theme woocommerce/emails folder and editing line 34:

```
echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( '[Web Order #%s]', 'woocommerce' )
```